# input[type=“file”]でディレクトリ選択した際、Chrome警告表示させない方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, html5, google-chrome

**質問**

```
<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory>
```

上記内容でディレクトリ選択した際、下記Chrome警告表示されるのですが、回避する方法はありますか？

> 2個のファイルをこのサイトにアップロードしますか？
>   「hoge」のすべてのファイルがアップロードされます。この操作は、サイトを信頼できる場合にのみ行ってください。

---

**試したこと**
Chrome「詳細設定」-「プライバシーとセキュリティ」-「サイトの設定」にある下記2つの項目で許可URLを追加してみたのですが、効果ありませんでした
・Cookie
・Javascript

**補足**
・恐らくセキュリティ考慮した結果だと思うのですが、自分専用用途の場合でも、警告表示回避できませんか？
・一番の目的は途中で処理を止めないことなので、警告表示されても、(ボタンクリックすることなく)警告を閉じる方法があればそれでも構いません

Comment: [How to remove warning message in Chrome when uploading a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50225019/9014308)の回答とか[Bootstrap File Input Folder Upload Demo - © Kartik](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-folder-upload-demo)末尾のコメントでは、オプションや対策は無いようです。一応S.O.回答コメントの、私は現象に遭遇していない＆"trust site"オプションかも？に +1 されてましたが、確かさは疑問ですし、1年以上経過しているので変わっている可能性もあります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome のソースコードを確認してみました。[file_select_helper.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/file_select_helper.cc?type=cs&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=261)

`<input type=file webkitdirectory>`をクリックしてファイル選択ダイアログからディレクトリを選択した場合、回避方法は存在しないと思われます。

`<input type=file webkitdirectory>`をクリックせずにアップロードしたいディレクトリをドラッグ&ドロップすると、そもそも確認ダイアログが出ないようです。しかし、これはバグのような気がするので将来は直されてしまうかもしれませんね。

Comment: Chromeのソースコードは公開されているのですね。検索してみてChromiumというオープンソースがあることを初めて知りました。ドラッグ&ドロップに関する情報も、参考になりました